# What goes into developing your own ePub reader android application?

Tags: android, pdf, epub

What are the prerequisites for developing an ePub reader for android? 
What will be the base for developing, the framework, library, etc. 
What will be the best approach to start with?

Mods: If this doesn't suit here then show me the way.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to parse the information inside the epub file and then do a proper representation of the data. epub is very close to XML/HTML so maybe you can make use of some xml/html parsers.

There is also an EpubParser but i dont know how mature it is: 
http://tika.apache.org/0.8/api/org/apache/tika/parser/epub/EpubParser.html

Answer (score 0):

FBReader does all this (and more) and is open source (GPL): https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ